# Check if array only has numbers that are allowed

Tags: c#

I've got two types:

```js
public enum GroupTypes : int
{
        Downtime = 1,

        Uptime = 2,
}
```

And then I have an array 
e.g.

```js
// first combo
int [] types = new Int32[] {1, 2};

//2nd
int [] types = new Int32[] {1};

//3rd
int [] types = new Int32[] {2};
```

array can only have 1, 2 or both types and no other are allowed.
If user enters wrong type, he gets an error.

however I struggle to check that. This is how I do that:

```js
// none types or more than two types added
if ((types == null || types.Length <= 0) || (types != null && types.Length > 1)) {
  return this.CreateApiError(ApiError.ApiErrors.BAD_REQUEST, "Incorrect types input", HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}

// contains non-existent type
if (!types.Where(a => a != 1 || a != 2).Select(x => true).FirstOrDefault()) {
  return this.CreateApiError(ApiError.ApiErrors.BAD_REQUEST, "Incorrect types input", HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```

the first `if` checks if length of types is fine and second should check if only type 1, type 2 or both are present and it doesn't contain non-existent types like 3, 11, ... .

I also tried `types.Any(a => a == 1 || a == 2)` but it just checks if 1 or 2 is present and will still say it's okay even if iI'll have `{1, 5}`

Comment: You can do `types.Any(x => x != 1 && x != 2)`  which returns true if any values are not 1 and 2

Comment: Why not use an array of your enum type?  Instead of `int [] types = new Int32[] {1, 2};` use `GroupTypes[] types = new GroupTypes[] {GroupTypes.Downtime, GroupTypes.Uptime};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jonathon Chase's answer works, but it's no good if for any reason you need to increase the number of group types. This version is more extensible.

```
if (types.Length == 0 || !types.All(x => Enum.IsDefined(typeof(GroupType), x)))
    return this.CreateApiError(ApiError.ApiErrors.BAD_REQUEST, "Incorrect types input", HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
```

Comment: This approach also works with string representations of the enum flag.

Answer (score 2):

You likely want to be using LINQ's `All` extension.

```
if(!types.All(a => a == 1 || a == 2))
    return this.CreateApiError(ApiError.ApiErrors.BAD_REQUEST, "Incorrect types input", HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
```

This will return true if all the values are 1 or 2, and false if any do not match.

You could also do this using `Any`. The issue with the predicate you tried is that you were only checking that any value matched one of your expected values. You would instead want to check that any value does not match one of your expected values. The following would work: `types.Any(a => a != 1 && a != 2)`

Comment: does this work even if only 1 or 2 is present, but not both?

Comment: @JoelTrauger Yes. if the List is only `[1]` or `[2]`, all of the elements in it will be 1 or 2.

Comment: @JoelTrauger Yes, because it's checking each item to see if it's 1 or 2, no matter how many items are in `types`.  Note that if `types` is empty that will not trip the `if` statement as `All` on an empty collection is always `true`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way, (Link live demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rhwtcB))

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        var validTypes = new [] {1, 2};
        var invalidTypes = new [] {1, 2, 3};

        Console.WriteLine(validTypes.Any(p => !Enum.IsDefined(typeof(GroupTypes), p)));
        Console.WriteLine(invalidTypes.Any(p => !Enum.IsDefined(typeof(GroupTypes), p)));


    }

    public enum GroupTypes
    {
            Downtime = 1,
            Uptime = 2
    }
}
```